# Access Google Calender JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json, google-calendar-api

I'm tiring to get holidays from google api here is my php code. which return json data from google corretcly

```
 $calendar_id = urlencode('japanese.ja@holiday.calendar.google.com');
        // 取得期間
        $start  = date("Y-01-01\T00:00:00\Z");
        $end = date("Y-12-31\T00:00:00\Z");
        $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.japanese%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=apikeyhere';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if (!empty($result)) {
            $json = json_decode($result);

                foreach($json->items as $mydata)

    {       
         foreach($mydata as $values)
         {
              echo $values->summary . "\n";
              echo $values->start. "\n";
         }

    }
```

I need to get summery and start from that data but above code show nothing, i tired using various foreach but didn't works. can someone help me please to get summery and start from it, thank you

**Here is the part output json from google calender v3**

```
  {
     "kind": "calendar#events",
     "etag": "\"p33sets73qumdi0g\"",
     "summary": "Holidays in Japan",
     "updated": "2018-02-16T08:53:55.000Z",
     "timeZone": "UTC",
     "accessRole": "reader",
     "defaultReminders": [],
     "nextSyncToken": "CMCd1N-HqtkCEAAYAQ==",
     "items": [
      {
       "kind": "calendar#event",
       "etag": "\"2778543254000000\"",
       "id": "20170109_60o30d9l6go30e1g60o30dr564",
       "status": "confirmed",
       "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MjAxNzAxMDlfNjBvMzBkOWw2Z28zMGUxZzYwbzMwZHI1NjQgZW4uamFwYW5lc2UjaG9saWRheUB2",
       "created": "2014-01-09T12:47:07.000Z",
       "updated": "2014-01-09T12:47:07.000Z",
       "summary": "Coming of Age Day",
       "creator": {
        "email": "en.japanese#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com",
        "displayName": "Holidays in Japan",
        "self": true
       },
       "organizer": {
        "email": "en.japanese#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com",
        "displayName": "Holidays in Japan",
        "self": true
       },
       "start": {
        "date": "2017-01-09"
       },
       "end": {
        "date": "2017-01-10"
       },
       "transparency": "transparent",
       "visibility": "public",
       "iCalUID": "20170109_60o30d9l6go30e1g60o30dr564@google.com",
       "sequence": 0
      },
      {
       "kind": "calendar#event",
       "etag": "\"2778543254000000\"",
       "id": "20170717_60o30d9lcgo30e1g60o30dr564",
       "status": "confirmed",
       "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MjAxNzA3MTdfNjBvMzBkOWxjZ28zMGUxZzYwbzMwZHI1NjQgZW4uamFwYW5lc2UjaG9saWRheUB2",
       "created": "2014-01-09T12:47:07.000Z",
       "updated": "2014-01-09T12:47:07.000Z",
       "summary": "Sea Day",
       "creator": {
        "email": "en.japanese#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com",
        "displayName": "Holidays in Japan",
        "self": true
       },
       "organizer": {
        "email": "en.japanese#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com",
        "displayName": "Holidays in Japan",
        "self": true
       },
       "start": {
        "date": "2017-07-17"
       },
       "end": {
        "date": "2017-07-18"
       },
       "transparency": "transparent",
       "visibility": "public",
       "iCalUID": "20170717_60o30d9lcgo30e1g60o30dr564@google.com",
       "sequence": 0
      },
      {
       "kind": "calendar#event",
       "etag": "\"2778543254000000\"",
       "id": "20170918_60o30d9lcko32e1g60o30dr564",
       "status": "confirmed",
       "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MjAxNzA5MThfNjBvMzBkOWxja28zMmUxZzYwbzMwZHI1NjQgZW4uamFwYW5lc2UjaG9saWRheUB2",
       "created": "2014-01-09T12:47:07.000Z",
       "updated": "2014-01-09T12:47:07.000Z",
       "summary": "Respect for the Aged Day",
       "creator": {
        "email": "en.japanese#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com",
        "displayName": "Holidays in Japan",
        "self": true
       },
       "organizer": {
        "email": "en.japanese#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com",
        "displayName": "Holidays in Japan",
        "self": true
       },
       "start": {
        "date": "2017-09-18"
       },
       "end": {
        "date": "2017-09-19"
       },
       "transparency": "transparent",
       "visibility": "public",
       "iCalUID": "20170918_60o30d9lcko32e1g60o30dr564@google.com",
       "sequence": 0
      },
      {
       "kind": "calendar#event",
       "etag": "\"2778543254000000\"",
       "id": "20171009_60o30d9l6ko30e1g60o30dr564",
       "status": "confirmed",
       "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MjAxNzEwMDlfNjBvMzBkOWw2a28zMGUxZzYwbzMwZHI1NjQgZW4uamFwYW5lc2UjaG9saWRheUB2",
       "created": "2014-01-09T12:47:07.000Z",
       "updated": "2014-01-09T12:47:07.000Z",
       "summary": "Sports Day",
       "creator": {
        "email": "en.japanese#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com",
        "displayName": "Holidays in Japan",
        "self": true
       },
       "organizer": {
        "email": "en.japanese#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com",
        "displayName": "Holidays in Japan",
        "self": true
       },
       "start": {
        "date": "2017-10-09"
       },
       "end": {
        "date": "2017-10-10"
       },
       "transparency": "transparent",
       "visibility": "public",
       "iCalUID": "20171009_60o30d9l6ko30e1g60o30dr564@google.com",
       "sequence": 0
      }

     ]
    }
```

**I converted this code from js code which have working json part

data variable is the json out put from google, i just need convert this part to php**

```
for (item in data.items) {
        $("#output").append(
          "<hr><h3>" + data.items[item].summary + "<h3>" +
          "<h4>" + data.items[item].start.date + "<h4>"
        );
      }
```

Comment: do you have an APIKEY ? if u do what's the print_r on $result

Comment: sorry key use for live site so i can't publish here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, you just have one `foreach` loop too many, once you are iterating over the items you can access their properties directly, no need to loop through them.

```
// Check if we got some results
if (!empty($result)) {

    // Parse the results
    $json = json_decode($result);

    // Iterate over the item property of the resultset
    foreach($json->items as $item) {

        // Each item is an object, 
        // 'summary' and 'start' are properties of 'item'
        // 'date' is a property of 'start'
        echo '<hr><h3>' . $item->summary . '</h3>';

        echo '<h4>' . $item->start->date . '</h4>';

    }
}
```

I changed the name of `$myData` to `$item`, I feel that it makes the code easier to understand, feel free to update the answer if you want to preserve the name `$mydata`.